# Why Javascript object didn't change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone explain me this strange js behavior ?

All of this is in AngularJS.

I have helper function in my main app.js to simply return element from an array by its id:

```
var MyLib = MyLib || {};

MyLib.helpers = {
    find: function(needle, stack) {
        for (var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
            if(stack[i]._id === needle)
                return stack[i];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I have factory and function to handle database change:

```
// categories are grabbed from db
var categories = [some array of objects];


// change is object returned from database that has all info about object as well as new object itself
function handleChange(change) {
    var _category = MyLib.helpers.find(change.id, categories);

    // if deleted, that part is ok
    if(change.deleted) {
        var idx = categories.indexOf(_category);
        if(idx !== -1) {
            categories.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    } else {
        // if updated that part is weird
        if(_category) {
            _category = change.doc;
        }
        // if newly added that part is ok
        else {
            categories.push( angular.copy(change.doc) );
        }
    }
}
```

Why when I try to update element grabbed from categories array doesn't update in categories array ?

```
// categories ARE NOT updated after this
_category = change.doc;
```

and only when I refer to categories by index like this:

```
// categories ARE updated after this although _category is returned from this array by index (find function)
var idx = categories.indexOf(_category);
categories[idx] = change.doc;
```

I don't understand this...

Comment: you are simply overwriting the value of the variable with a new value. Reference to prior object value is gone then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the variable with a new value and any reference to prior value is gone.

Instead of overwriting the original object value with a new object you could update the existing object using `angular.extend()`

```
angular.extend(_category, change.doc);
```

Comment: I get it now. I thought that reference will persist, when in this case it is overwriten. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't analyze everything, but you should always have dot notation.

_category pass by value, and will not change when 'MyLib.hel ...' is changed

```
var _category = MyLib.helpers.find(change.id, categories);
```

something.category pass by reference, and will be changed when 'MyLib.hel ...' is changed

```
var something.category = MyLib.helpers.find(change.id, categories);
```